# Download ParseObject from Parse and Display

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, parse-platform

I am developing and application in xamarin for android. There are two buttons one for uploading the Parse object and another one for downloading the object and display Image. Uploading button is working properly. But I am facing two main Problem

First: I am getting a null value in my IEnumerable object. I have attached a screenshot of my breakpoint value.
[image: BreakPoint null object]

Second: When I am trying to display the object I am getting an error. I have attached a screenshot of the error shown

[image: error]

Upload Button:

```
upbutton.Click += async delegate {
            try {
                byte[] myfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (path);
                ParseFile file = new ParseFile ("imgfl.png", myfile);
                await file.SaveAsync ();

                // link your file object to your Parse object
                ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject ("GameScore");
                gameScore ["score"] = 0001;
                gameScore ["playerName"] = " Bob";
                gameScore ["image"] = file;
                await gameScore.SaveAsync ();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.Console.WriteLine (e);
            }


        };
```

Download Button:

```
downbutton.Click+= async delegate {

            var query = from GameScore in ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScore")
                orderby GameScore.CreatedAt descending
                select GameScore;
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();

//I am getting a null object result here
            foreach (var obj in results)
            {
                ParseFile img = obj.Get<ParseFile>("image");


                _imageView.SetImageURI(img.Url);
                //error here
            }


        };
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your `GameScore` rows probably doesn't have the `image` property set, for that row you'll get a `null` result in your `img` variable.

Also note that in your Download Button code, you're going to get every single row and keep calling `_imageView.SetImageURI(img.Url)` line for each one, potentially replacing the value over and over again.

You might want to be doing a `FirstAsync()` call instead of `FindAsync()` if you are going to want just a single row.

Comment: actually after downloading all object from the parse I want to display them in a list view. the "image" and "playerName". I am new to android so I donthave much knowledge about Its UI control. Can you please help me with this. thanks a lot